# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.One or more issues found when checking AAR

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Hasan Mohamad\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\41a83d0cf61e3d2ab42ea706b65148ab\transformed\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Hasan Mohamad\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\bb9a53f8c4dc071c681fa071739dc70b\transformed\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Hasan Mohamad\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\41a83d0cf61e3d2ab42ea706b65148ab\transformed\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

     The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Hasan Mohamad\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\bb9a53f8c4dc071c681fa071739dc70b\transformed\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: I tried every thing on the stack over flow and nothing work until now

Answer (score 3):

In project_folder/android/app/build.gradle,

1. update value of `compileSdkVersion to 31`
2. update value of `targetSdkVersion to 31`